# ssv file to pandas dataframe-like format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I open ssv file with ssv.loadf, I get data like this:

```
import ssv
new_table = ssv.loadf('train.ssv')
new_table
[['0.113446 0.118114 0.160286\n0.335122 0.299763 0.310816\n]]
```

Can you help me to separate these columns like in pandas DataFrame?

In this example I want to have dataframe with 3 columns and 2 rows
Is there any command that can open ssv file in readable format like in pandas?
I can't find any info regarding ssv files

Can somebody please help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you post your exact code, and file content?

Comment: Here it is, I just cut final table

Comment: you can use pandas, `pd.read_csv('train.ssv', sep='\s+', header=None)`, or `pd.read_fwf('train.ssv', header=None)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments below your question provide you with the possible solution of importing your dataset as a dataframe. Also, a similar question can be found [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26333/convert-a-list-of-lists-into-a-pandas-dataframe). Here is my try to provide an adequate answer to your question/

```
from pandas import DataFrame
new_table=[['0.113446 0.118114 0.160286\n0.335122 0.299763 0.310816\n']]
#This list will be contain every line as a list
y=[]
for first in new_table:
    for i in first[0].split('\n')[:-1]:
        y.append(i.split(" "))
df=DataFrame.from_records(y, columns=["First","Second","Third"])
```